# Google Cloud Functions Error: "Cannot decode type from Firestore Value"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

Using Firestore in a React app, Im testing out using Google Cloud Functions to grab a document field, and then create a new field in Firestore using that field.   I had it working the other day and now it is not.

This is the error that Im getting in the Google Cloud Function log:

> Error: Cannot decode type from Firestore Value: {"stringValue":"sox"}
>   at DocumentSnapshot._decodeValue

Below is the code I used. It is very similar to the code here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#writing_data

```
exports.createShowDoubleName = functions.firestore
  .document('shows/{showId}')
  .onUpdate((event) => {
    const data = event.data.data();
    const previousData = event.data.previous.data();
    if (data.name == previousData.name) return;
    var name = data.name;
    var newname = name+"_"+name
     return event.data.ref.set({
        newname: newname
      }, {merge: true});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firebase-functions SDK [version 0.7.5](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases/tag/v0.7.5) is supposed to fix the problem.  It now forces a peer dependency on firebase-admin 5.5.0.  Get it:

```
npm install firebase-functions@0.7.5
```

Comment: Thanks Doug.  firebase-functions SDK 0.7.5 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to reproduce the error when running the latest version (0.7.4) of `firebase-functions`.

You must be running an older version because the current version of `firebase-functions` requires a trigger function to return a Promise or value.  With the current version, this statement produces an error:

```
if (data.name == previousData.name) return;
```

and must be changed to:

```
if (data.name == previousData.name) return null;
```

Suggest you upgrade `firebase-functions` by running this command in the `functions` folder of your project:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and same error. After upgrading both firebase-functions and firebase-admin (npm install firebase-functions@latest --save) and (npm install firebase-admin@latest --save) it solved the issue. Delving further into the logs the issue seems to be in an old version of firebase-admin. I am now running admin version 5.5.1 and functions version 0.7.4.

Comment: What were the old versions?

Comment: Old versions were 5.4.2 for admin, and 0.7.1 for functions

Answer (score 1):

Definitely just need to update something.

Open your terminal **navigate to the functions folder** and run this update from there:

`npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save`